# how can i access this inside items in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this code

```
Ext.define('Header', {

getItems: function() {
    return somepanel;
}

items: [this.getItems()]

});
```

This is not working. i get error that getItems is not defined

Comment: Think about the evaluation order. This is where you're defining a class. You're trying to call an instance method to set a class level configuration.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli thanks for that, i think i got what you are saying and i have realised the mistake. but i still not able to correct my thing. i am new to extjs. can you please help me on how should i have done it the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, however, you can add a template method:

```
Ext.define('MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = this.createItems();
        this.callParent();
    },

    createItems: function() {
        return [{title: 'Foo'}];
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much , i got it working now, i was calling it after callparent. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

**this** is the context where Ext.define('Header'...) is being executed. I guess that's the **window**.

I don't get properly what you want to do, but if you want to fill item property with the function you need to call it:

```
items: function() {
    return somepanel;
}()
```

Comment: I am able to do that if i have function defined in separate file and then i can use this   `items: [Header.getHeader1(),Menu.getpanel2()]` THis worked fine but not if they are in same class. basically i have many panels in different function which i want to insert as items

Comment: Ok, I've got you. Extjs gives few ways to do it. Try to use inheritance mechanics: put the common routines in common class and redefine items in constructor, or plugins - essentially it's the same, take a look at plugins example.